# Overwrite object in array if the product ID is the same and no placeholders which are Null

Tags: java

i need to be able in the SoppingCart with the method "addItem" to add products with the same pid number to already existing objects in the array and overwrite the old one. At the same time there should not exist placeholder with no content in the array.

I think the way i tried will not work, but i do not really know how it is possible.

This is the class:

```
public class ShoppingCart {

public Item[] cart;
int temporary;
int totalAmountB;
int totalAmountM;
int totalAmountD;
int totalAmountF;

public ShoppingCart() {

}

 public void addItem(Item toAdd) {



     if(toAdd instanceof Grocery) {

         if(toAdd.pid==1) {

         totalAmountB+=Grocery.getPacketCount();

         cart[0]=new Grocery(toAdd.pid, toAdd.signifier, toAdd.pricePerUnit, Grocery.getExpiryDate(), totalAmountB);
         }

         if(toAdd.pid==2) {

         totalAmountM+=Grocery.getPacketCount(); 
         cart[1]=new Grocery(toAdd.pid, toAdd.signifier, toAdd.pricePerUnit, Grocery.getExpiryDate(), totalAmountM); 
         }
     }

     if(toAdd instanceof Article) {

         if(toAdd.pid==3) {

         totalAmountD+=Article.getAmount();
         cart[2]=new Article(toAdd.pid, toAdd.signifier, toAdd.pricePerUnit, "lfdm", totalAmountD);

         }
         if(toAdd.pid==4) {

         totalAmountF+=Article.getAmount();
         cart[3]=new Article(toAdd.pid, toAdd.signifier, toAdd.pricePerUnit, "qm", totalAmountF);

         }
     }


 }
```

main-method

```
public class ShoppingMall {

public static void main(String[] args){

    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("Ihr digitaler Warenkorb:");

    boolean loop = true;
    int item = 0;
    String action = "";
    int pckg;
    float amount = 0.0f;



    ShoppingCart basket = new ShoppingCart();

    while (loop) {
        System.out.println("\nWelcher Artikel soll bearbeitet werden");
        System.out.println("------------------------------");
        System.out.println("1 Butter");
        System.out.println("2 Milch");
        System.out.println("3 Draht");
        System.out.println("4 Fliesen");           
        System.out.println("\nSie haben den Einkauf abgeschlossen?\nWaehlen Sie zwischen: ");
        System.out.println("------------------------------");
        System.out.println("5 Warenkorb ausgeben");
        System.out.println("0 Exit\n");
        System.out.print("Ihre Eingabe bitte: ");

        try{
            item = Integer.valueOf(input.readLine());


            if((item < 5) && (item > 0))
            {
                //System.out.println("\n------------------------------");
                do{
                    System.out.print("Waehlen Sie + fuer hinzufuegen oder - fuer entfernen. ");
                    action = input.readLine();
                }while(!action.equals("+") && !action.equals("-"));
            }

            //if(action.equals("+") || action.equals("-"))
            //{
                switch (item) {
                    case 1: {
                        System.out.print("Wieviele Packungen Butter ? ");
                        pckg = Integer.valueOf(input.readLine());
                        Grocery groc = new Grocery(1,"Butter",1.59f,20180618,pckg);
                        if(action.equals("+"))
                            basket.addItem(groc);
                        else
                            basket.removeItem(groc);
                        break;
                    }
                    case 2: {                        
                        System.out.print("Wieviele Packungen Milch ? ");
                        pckg = Integer.valueOf(input.readLine());
                        Grocery groc = new Grocery(2,"Milch",1.09f,20180618,pckg);
                        if(action.equals("+"))
                            basket.addItem(groc);
                        else
                            basket.removeItem(groc);
                        break;
                    }
                    case 3: {
                        System.out.print("Wieviele laufende Meter (lfdm) Draht? ");
                        amount = Float.valueOf(input.readLine());
                        Article art = new Article(3,"Draht",0.36f,"lfdm",amount);
                        if(action.equals("+"))
                            basket.addItem(art);
                        else
                            basket.removeItem(art);

                        break;
                    }
                    case 4: {

                        System.out.print("Wieviele Quadratmeter (qm) Fliesen ? ");
                        amount = Float.valueOf(input.readLine());
                        Article art = new Article(4,"Fliesen",20.00f,"qm",amount);
                        if(action.equals("+"))
                            basket.addItem(art);
                        else
                            basket.removeItem(art);

                        break;
                    }
                    case 5: {
                        System.out.println("\nIn Ihrem Warenkorb befindet sich:\n");
                        System.out.println("Artikel     Menge         Preis/Einheit             Preis");
                        System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------");
                        System.out.println(basket);
                        System.out.print("\nWeiter mit beliebiger Taste!");
                        input.readLine();
                        break;
                    }
                    case 0: {
                        loop = false;
                        System.out.println("\nProgramm beendet");
                        break;
                    }   
                    default:
                        System.out.println("Ihre Eingabe wurde nicht erkannt!\n");

                }
            //}
            //else
            //  System.out.println("Ihre Eingabe wurde nicht erkannt!\n");

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("\nFalsche Eingabe:\nLebensmittel werden nur in ganzen Packungen abgegeben!\n"
                               + "Non- Food Produkte auch in Bruchteilen der jeweiligen Einheit\n"
                               + "Geben sie eine ganze Zahl bei Lebensmitteln ein oder eine \n"
                               + "Gleitpunktzahl bei Non- Food Produkten.");
        }
    }       
}
```

Comment: I guess you are learning java and thus not pointing out design mistakes. You can use `Map` or preferably `HashMap` to start with to add items using pid as key. This way, the items would itself replace if you add again under same pid.

Comment: Also check your code `totalAmountB+=Grocery.getPacketCount();` . Doesn't seem right to me. You can't ask homework questions here if it is but can only post things you have tried and doesn't work. Have a look at guidelines : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What happened with your earlier question and why are you insisting on creating new objects all the time instead of reusing the ones you already have? Add a new method add(Item other) in your Item class and then implement it in your subclasses and keep your counter inside the subclass instead as a member in ShoppingCart.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Yes that´s actually what it says in the task. I already have two other add-methods in the subclasses, but I didn´t know what  they were actually for. There is only one add-method called in the main-method . Is there only a counter in this subclasses and how can i call the methods in the subclasses? I tried all the time to work only with this single add-method

Comment: The addItem method in ShoppingCart has nothing to do with the addItem method in Item, they just have the same name, it's two different things to add a new item to the shopping cart and to update the quantity of an item in the shopping cart. I think you need to understand that difference and determine which class should handle that. One problem with your solution and that might lead to confusion is that Butter for instance is both a product and an item, maybe you need to separate them. Didn't you write the `Item` class and `Article` and `Grocery` yourself?